# Notification with phone call state

Tags: android, notifications, phone-call

I don't want to play notification sound if phone call is active, and if notification sound is playing at that time and a call is ringing, the notification sound should be stopped.

I tried the following code but I can't get the current phone state.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) 
context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), 
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    //private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged";
    Context context; //Context to make Toast if required 
    public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //when Idle i.e no call
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //when Off hook i.e in call
            //Make intent and start your service here
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Off hook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            //when Ringing
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use broadcastreceiver for this purpose like this and based on the state disable the notifications:

```
public class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        int state = 0;
        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }

    }
}
```

and in manifest.xml file:

```
 <receiver android:name=".PhonecallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Hello @masoudVali when i call to other user, which state come?

Comment: you can check outgoing call by this `intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)`

Answer (score 0):

During on phone call, `onCallStateChanged()` we can get state of phone call. for stop notification sound try this:

```
try {
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
ringtone .stop();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Happy coding!!